# I am getting error while I opening a file

Tags: python, list, file

```
import os
import sys
file = os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop/python_programing/python_projects/12dicts-6.0.2/agid.txt')
try:
    with open(file) as in_file:
        loaded_txt = in_file.read()
        loaded_txt = [x.lower() for x in loaded_txt]
        print (loaded_txt)
except IOError as e:
    print("{}\nError opening {}. Terminating program." .format(e, file), file=sys.stderr)
    sys,exit(1)


file_to_open = os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop/movie_quotes.txt')
```

---

while running the above code I am getting following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/pavandadi/Desktop/python_programing/python_projects/exception.py", line 6, in <module>
    loaded_txt = in_file.read()
  File "/Users/pavandadi/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 2921: invalid continuation byte
```

what to do?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#reading-and-writing-unicode-data

Comment: Is your text file encoded properly as UTF-8? Is it potentially encoded differently? Perhaps you need to specify a different `encoding` value (and mode flags) to the `open` command, or append `decode("whatever-encoding")` to the `read()` call?

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to decode it after read it like that

```
with open(file) as in_file:
        loaded_txt = in_file.read()
        loaded_txt = [x.lower() for x in loaded_txt]
        print (loaded_txt.decode('UTF-8')) #or any encoding type you want
```

Comment: I usewith open(file,'rb') as in_file:
        loaded_txt = in_file.read()
        loaded_txt = [x.lower() for x in loaded_txt]
        print (loaded_txt)